# How to modify user input?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I wrote an little demo code, to show you my problem:

```
puts "Enter your feeling"
a = gets.chomp
@feel = "good"
puts a
```

SO when it comes to the input, i type in:

```
Actually i fell very #{@feel}
```

Then i hope to get this output:

```
 Actually i fell very good
```

But instead i get this output:

```
 Actually i fell very #{@feel}
```

What did i make wrong?

Comment: do you have two different models?

Comment: why? i dont see a problem! I have an friends model and the setting model

Comment: your models need to be associated, i.e the salution model belongs_to the user model

Comment: Thanks but i know this! the problem is that rails escapes the ruby code inside an input!

Comment: What are the fields of friend model.

Comment: You need to post more of the surrounding code, there isn't enough context here to understand how you're printing the salutation.

Comment: And how looks your `salutation` method? Where does is get `@friend` from?

Comment: I updated my question completly! Please review it again

Comment: Maybe you should start a new question instead?

Comment: What are you going to "allow" to be interpolated?  What can go in the `{}`'s, **anything**?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It honestly isn't too safe to interpolate arbitrary strings from the user.  Basically it's the same as using [Kernel#eval](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0.0/Kernel.html#method-i-eval) (which will work in your case) ... the user can put whatever they want and it is extremely easy to abuse and compromise your system.  You could technically do a little by simply filtering out quotation marks in what they type, but honestly it's a bad choice.

What you can do is do a string replace for `#{@feel}` with `@feel`, if `@feel` is the only thing you are going to allow them to interpolate:

```
puts a.gsub('#{@feel}',@feel)
```

Answer (score 0):

instead of

```
puts a
```

it should be

```
puts "Actually i feel very " + @feel
```

Answer (score 0):

> "#{@feel}"

may be this what you need I **feel**.

and try to follow naming conventions.

Answer (score 0):

Simple answer is you can't.

Interpolation happens at run time, so even if you could get this to work, @feel would be nil at the time you input it.

You would be better doing something like:

```
puts "Enter your feeling"
a = gets.chomp
@feel = "good"
puts a.gsub("##feel##",@feel)
```

Then asked how you feel enter:

```
   Actually I feel very ##feel##
```